# Declaring certain variables in shader causes it to stop working? (GLSL)

Tags: glsl

I'm using GLSL.

I have a simple fragment shader here:

```
 "uniform sampler2D backBuffer;",
 "uniform float r;",
 "uniform float g;",
 "uniform float b;",
 "uniform float ratio;",
 "void main() {",
 "  vec4 color;",
 "  float avg, dr, dg, db, multiplier;",
 "  color = texture2D(backBuffer, vec2(gl_TexCoord[0].x * 1,gl_TexCoord[0].y * 1));",
 "  avg = (color.r + color.g + color.b) / 3.0;",
 "  dr = avg * r;",
 "  dg = avg * g;",
 "  db = avg * b;",
 "  color.r =  color.r * (gl_TexCoord[0].x * gl_TexCoord[0].y);",
"   color.g =  color.g * (gl_TexCoord[0].x * gl_TexCoord[0].y);",
"   color.b =  color.b * (gl_TexCoord[0].x * gl_TexCoord[0].y);",
 "  gl_FragColor = color;",
 "}"
```

Now it works just fine.

However, for some very strange reason, adding any more variables such as a vec2 or float causes it to have no effect on my scene:

```
 "uniform sampler2D backBuffer;",
 "uniform float r;",
 "uniform float g;",
 "uniform float b;",
 "uniform float ratio;",
 "void main() {",
 "  vec4 color;",
 "  float avg, dr, dg, db, multiplier;",
 "  vec2 divisors;",
 "  color = texture2D(backBuffer, vec2(gl_TexCoord[0].x * 1,gl_TexCoord[0].y * 1));",
 "  avg = (color.r + color.g + color.b) / 3.0;",
 "  dr = avg * r;",
 "  dg = avg * g;",
 "  db = avg * b;",
 "  color.r =  color.r * (gl_TexCoord[0].x * gl_TexCoord[0].y);",
"   color.g =  color.g * (gl_TexCoord[0].x * gl_TexCoord[0].y);",
"   color.b =  color.b * (gl_TexCoord[0].x * gl_TexCoord[0].y);",
 "  gl_FragColor = color;",
 "}"
```

In this one I added a vec2 called divisors, that's all I did and the shader no longer does anything to the pixels.

Why is this? Is there something I do not understand about variable declaration in GLSL?

Thanks

Comment: Check the error logs (call glGetShaderInfoLog) after compiling and after linking the shaders -- they might tell you something useful

Comment: @Chris Dodd The string returns an empty string.

Comment: Untagged the languages, as this has nothing to do with either C or C++.

Comment: @Christian Rau Nope, NVidia 9400m

Comment: I would rule out exceeding the instruction limit as a) the shader is short and b) being unused, divisors wouldn't get compiled in. But really `glGetShaderInfoLog` will not return an empty string if there's a problem with the shader... Anyway, your syntax is perfectly fine if this is what you are wondering.

Comment: Actually, after editing out all your quotes, I realized that each line was a quoted string separated by commas. In C/C++ you would usually just juxtapose quoted strings when creating a single big string, so I wonder if you are doing something strange like initializing an array of strings and not taking into account that its size has changed after adding a new line?

Comment: @UncleZeiv thats it. Put in answer form to get cookie.

Comment: thanks, I'll also revert my editing otherwise it doesn't make sense!

Comment: If the described solution is correct, then the infolog string would have had a syntax error message in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I notice that each line is a quoted string separated by commas. In C/C++ you would usually just juxtapose quoted strings when creating a single big string, so I wonder if you are doing something strange like initializing an array of strings and not taking into account that its size has changed after adding a new line?